# Aligning pieces of equations on the right

Tags: align

I would like to write an environment to write linear system of equations that could be used with

```
\begin{linearSystem}
2x&+y&=&2\\
x&-3y&=&1
\end {linearSystem}
```

and should display

```
2x +y=2
 x-3y=1
```

Every piece of equation should be aligned on the right and no spacing should be added.

I have tried to use the aligned environment with

```
\[\left\{\begin{aligned}[c]
2x&+y&=&2\\
x&-3y&=&1
\end{aligned}\right.\]
```

But I get something like

```
2x+y  =2
 x-3y =1
```

which is not what I want. Is there a way to have an "aligned" environment that justifies everything on the right and that does not introduce any spacing every 2 "pieces" of equation.

Comment: Did you tried \hfill? like the below code `\begin{eqnarray*}
\hfill 2x+y=2\\
\hfill 3y=1
\end {eqnarray*}
`

Comment: @TVM Boy: I would like the environment to work without using any \hfill. Moreover, it won't remove the extra space that is added by the aligned environment.

Answer (score 5):

It is already possible with the `systeme` package. Why reinvent the wheel?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

 \[ \systeme{2x + y = 2, x-3y= 1} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm using instead of `systeme` package (it was my first thought - the same thought of @Bernard ) `spalign` package that it works, if we use the correct syntax, the same. It is very important that the blank spaces into `\spalignsys` should not be removed otherwise there is no alignment of the variables.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign}

\begin{document}
\[ 
\spalignsys{2x + y = 2; x - 3y = 1}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've made me discover this package (+1). Thanks!

Comment: @Bernard Aahahaha :-) also Zarko has written the similar your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an environment for linear systems. It's not exactly what you describe because, it is designed to align also the signs. It's more difficult to use (more `&`) but I think that the result is better.

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{xparse}


 \ExplSyntaxOn
 \makeatletter

 \cs_new_protected:Nn \__insideloop_system_cr:
   {
     \scan_stop:
     \group_align_safe_begin:
     \peek_meaning_remove:NTF * \__insideloop_system_cr_i: \__insideloop_system_cr_i:
   }
 \cs_new_protected:Nn \__insideloop_system_cr_i:
   {
     \peek_meaning:NTF [ % ]
       \__insideloop_system_cr_ii:
       { \__insideloop_system_cr_ii: [ \c_zero_dim ] }
   }
 \cs_new_protected:Npn \__insideloop_system_cr_ii: [ #1 ]
   {
     \group_align_safe_end:
     \cr
     \noalign { \skip_vertical:n { #1 } \scan_stop: }
   }
 \NewDocumentEnvironment { system } { }
   {
     \group_begin:
     \cs_set_eq:NN \\ \__insideloop_system_cr:
     \left \{ \null \,
     \vcenter
     \bgroup \spread@equation
     \ialign
       \bgroup
          \strut \hfil $##$ & $##$ \hfil && \enspace $##$ \enspace &
          \hfil $##$ & $##$ \hfil \crcr
   }
   {      \crcr
       \egroup
     \egroup
     \right.
     \group_end:
   }

 \makeatother
 \ExplSyntaxOff



 \begin{document}


 $\begin{system}
 3 & x & + & 4 & y & + & 5 & z & = & 0 \\
 & x & - & 2 & y & - & & z & = & 7 \\
 -7 & x & + & 3 & y & + & 9 & z & = & 12
 \end{system}$

 \end{document}
```

[image: Result of the code above]